# How to pass Object with string using jade command line

Tags: pug

I want to execute the following jade command line passing an object containing integer and string.

> node node_modules\jade\bin\jade.js -P  -O [{"field1":1,"field2":"valstring/obj1"},{"field1":2,"field2":"valstring/obj2"}] inventaire-all.jade

I get the following

> ReferenceError: valstring is not defined

```
at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\web-generator-jadePart\node_modules\jade\bin\jade.js:68:38), <anonymous>:1:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\web-generator-jadePart\node_modules\jade\bin\jade.js:68:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

Anybody to help me ?

I can't find any answer on the forum

Thanks for your help, I'm totally blocked
Regards

Vpl

Answer (score 0):

Do

> jade.js -P  --obj "[{\"field1\":2,\"field2\":\"valstring/obj2\"},{\"field1\":3,\"field2\":\"valstri
>   ng/obj3\"}]" inventaire-all.jade